# Why pointer to function can't bind to lvalue reference, while function can?

Tags: c++, templates, reference, function-pointers

What's the difference between using a function name with and without an ampersand? I've noticed that they behave in a different way when bound to a template parameter:

```
void foo();
template <typename F> void bind(F&);
bind(foo);  // OK
bind(&foo); // Error
```

Why is it so? What is the deduced type in these cases?

Comment: Same reason as for `int a; void bind(int&);`: You can say `bind(a)` but not `bind(&a)`.

Answer (score 4):

Note that built-in [operator&](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access#Built-in_address-of_operator) will return a **prvalue** of type `T*`. So `&foo` will return a function pointer with type `void (*)()`, which is a prvalue and can't be bound to lvalue reference to non-const; that is just what `bind()` expects as it's parameter, then it fails.

For `bind(foo)`, template pamareter `F` will be deduced as the function type exactly (i.e. `void()`), then the argument type of `bind` will be `void(&)()`, so it works.

You might think `foo` and `&foo` should have the same effect because of the function-to-pointer decay. But note that the parameter of `bind()` is declared as passing-by-reference. Then for the `bind(foo)`, function-to-pointer decay doesn't happen, that's why the argument type is deduced as reference to function. On the other hand, for `bind(&foo)`, `operator&` is invoked explicitly to return a function pointer prvalue, which can't be passed to `bind()`.

If the parameter is declared as passing-by-value, function-to-pointer decay happens, then `bind(foo)` and `bind(&foo)` would have the same effect and both would work fine.

```
void foo();
template <typename F> void bind(F);
bind(foo);  // OK, F=void(*)()
bind(&foo); // same as above
```

Answer (score 2):

`&foo` is an *anonymous temporary* so it can't bind to a non-`const` reference.

If you had written

```
template <typename F> void bind(const F&);
```

then compilation would have been successful.

---

`foo` is not an anonymous temporary so the binding to a reference is allowed.